# Socket.io not always working

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, reactjs

I'm working with a few modules and everything is inplace EXCEPT for the fact that socket.io isn't always working...

We've got a few 'routes' we're already using in Socket.io, which all work great and work everytime!

But now, we're introducing a new one
'order/new', which should display every new order incomming.

A new order get's created, a message is sent over the queue, we retreive it through a GET request and we sent it to the user with Socket.io.

But the emit function doesn't always 'emit'(?!)...
Can anyone help me with this?

Server:

```js
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // somewhere else calls this function, nothing wrong here...
    function (mes) {
        console.log('New order received: ', mes);
        var doc_id = JSON.parse(mes)._id;
        request
            .get(urls['order/get'].replace(':id', doc_id))
            .end(function (err, res) {
                console.log(err);
                if (res.ok) {
                    console.log(chalk.green('OK: [GET] - ORDER/GET - ORDER_ID: ' + doc_id));
                    // The above console.log get's called, so still working...
                    socket.emit('order/new', res.body);
                    // THIS socket.emit is called randomly, it doesn't work everytime...
                } else {
                    console.log(chalk.red('ERROR: [GET] - ORDER/GET - ' + res.text))
                }
            });
    }
```

Front (React):

```js
var OrdersViewer = React.createClass({

    setNewOrder (order) {
        console.log("new order gotten nr.", this.state.orders.length);
        // this doesn't always get called...
        var orders = _.cloneDeep(this.state.orders);
        orders.push(order);
        this.setState({orders});
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        socket.on('order/new', this.setNewOrder)
    },

    render() {
        // renders stuff
    }
});
```

If any more info is needed, please say so in the comments below
Everything is up to date (Node.js, React.js, Socket.io etc)

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem with setNewOrder.

```
    var OrdersViewer = React.createClass({

            setNewOrder (order) {
                    console.log("new order gotten nr.", this.state.orders.length);
                    // this doesn't always get called...
                    var orders = _.cloneDeep(this.state.orders);
                    orders.push(order);
                    //this.setState({orders});
                    this.setState({orders: orders});
            },

            componentDidMount() {
                    socket.on('order/new', this.setNewOrder)
            },

            render() {
                    // renders stuff
            }
    });
```